# Modify text in cookie consent extension in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have the TYPO3 extension dp_cookieconsent.

I can not find a way to actually modify the opt in check boxes. I can not modify the text and not what boxes should appear. How can I do that?

I tried using the constants editor. But there I can only edit some very very basic setting.

Comment: The documentation of the Extension gives you all possibilities to configure the consent (text changes, select box enabling/disabling, etc.). Did you read it?

Comment: yes i did read it multiple times. But i cant find a way to add boxes for example.

Answer (score 1):

In general you have FLUID templates, which can be replaced with templates of your own.
Therefore you need to copy the original template file from the extension into your site extension, make the desired modifications and then add the path of your templates to the `paths` definitions.

in your case you can define typoscript constants, which gets used by the extension:

possible constants:

```
plugin.tx_cookieconsent.view.templateRootPath = EXT:my_site_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/dpcookieconsent/
plugin.tx_cookieconsent.view.partialRootPath = EXT:my_site_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/dpcookieconsent/
plugin.tx_cookieconsent.view.layoutRootPath = EXT:my_site_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts/dpcookieconsent/
```

or you add it into the setup:

```
plugin.tx_dpcookieconsent.view {
  templateRootPaths.10 = EXT:my_site_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/dpcookieconsent/
  partialRootPaths.10 = EXT:my_site_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/dpcookieconsent/
  layoutRootPaths.10 = EXT:my_site_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts/dpcookieconsent/
}
```

---

if you only want to change the existing strings for another language the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/p/dirkpersky/typo3-dp_cookieconsent/11.6/en-us/Configuration/Language.html) gives clear instructions for changing the labels to your language.

```
plugin.tx_dp_cookieconsent._LOCAL_LANG {
    de {
        message = XXX
        dismiss = XXX
        allow = XXX
        link = XXX
        deny = XXX
        allowall = XXX

        # Checkbox labels
        dpRequire = XXX
        dpStatistik = XXX
        dpMarketing = XXX

        # Iframe Overlay text
        media.notice = XXX
        media.desc = XXX
        media.btn = XXX
    }
}
```

of course you also can override the given language file strings.